# Complications When Calculating Moran's Index in R

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I am running the following code:

```
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spdep/versions/1.2-8/topics/nb2listw
# https://mgimond.github.io/simple_moransI_example/
library(spdeb)
nb <- poly2nb(my_file, queen=TRUE)
lw <- nb2listw(nb, style="W", zero.policy=TRUE) 
# moran(my_file$counts, lw, length(nb), Szero(lw))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error in print.listw(x) : 
  regions with no neighbours found, use zero.policy=TRUE
```

However, I have already specified `zero.policy = TRUE`. This makes me confused as to why my code is not working. I tried specifying the TRUE argument in other ways, e.g.

```
> nb2listw(nb, style="W", zero.policy="TRUE") 
Error in nb2listw(nb, style = "W", zero.policy = "TRUE") : 
  is.logical(zero.policy) is not TRUE
> nb2listw(nb, style="W", zero.policy='TRUE') 
Error in nb2listw(nb, style = "W", zero.policy = "TRUE") : 
  is.logical(zero.policy) is not TRUE
```

But in both these cases, I still get errors.

Is there some other way to specify these arguments?

My files look something like this:

```
    > nb
    Neighbour list object:
    Number of regions: 114 
    Number of nonzero links: 476 
    Percentage nonzero weights: 3.662665 
    Average number of links: 4.175439 
    11 regions with no links:
    4 6 10 11 23 95 107 111 112 113 114


> dput(nb)
structure(list(c(2L, 92L), c(1L, 3L, 5L, 92L, 94L), 2L, 0L, c(2L, 
8L), 0L, c(8L, 9L, 12L, 22L, 24L), c(5L, 7L, 9L, 24L), 7:8, 0L, 
    0L, c(7L, 13L, 15L, 22L), c(12L, 14L, 15L, 21L), c(13L, 21L, 
    98L), .....class = "nb", region.id = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",  ..... call = poly2nb(pl = MORAN, 
    queen = TRUE), type = "queen", sym = TRUE)


> head(my_file)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 5 fields
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5806005 ymin: 1435649 xmax: 5967651 ymax: 1638365
Projected CRS: NAD83 /
    ID_1         ID_2   LANDAREA ID_3 counts                       geometry
1 46010001 2021S051646010001  2811.9569    46      2 MULTIPOLYGON (((5911850 156...
```

Comment: Is this a typo: `library(spdeb)` ? You should try and make your code as close as possible to something we can cut and paste so we can try and replicate your problems in order to solve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate this using sample data from the example code in the help for "st_read".

```
> example(st_read)
```

That gives me `nc` to play with. I'll take a subset that forms some disconnected areas:

```
> d = nc[c(1:10, 40:50),]
```

Plotting this object will show you clear disconnected groups. Okay, lets form the neighbour structures:

```
> nb <- poly2nb(d, queen=TRUE)
> lw <- nb2listw(nb, style="W") 
Error in nb2listw(nb, style = "W") : Empty neighbour sets found
```

Expected that error since there's a disconnected area. Try the zero policy option:

```
> lw <- nb2listw(nb, style="W", zero.policy=TRUE)
```

And that works. Let's print the object:

```
> print(lw)
Error in print.listw(lw) : 
  regions with no neighbours found, use zero.policy=TRUE
```

So the error happens when you *print* the object (either explicitly like this or implicitly when you type the object name). I'm not sure how your code is producing an error from `print.listw` when your code only shows an assignment to `lw`, but maybe you've left out a print line?

You can add the zero policy option to print to get round this:

```
> print(lw, zero.policy=TRUE)
Characteristics of weights list object:
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 21 
Number of nonzero links: 30 
Percentage nonzero weights: 6.802721 
Average number of links: 1.428571 
2 regions with no links:
41 49

Weights style: W 
Weights constants summary:
   n  nn S0       S1       S2
W 19 361 19 26.33333 78.66667
```

The code in the `print.listw` function raises the error if there are any zero neighbours and you've either not specified the `zero.policy` argument in the call to `print` or you've set an `spdep` option called `zeroPolicy`:

```
if (is.null(zero.policy)) 
    zero.policy <- get("zeroPolicy", envir = .spdepOptions)
stopifnot(is.logical(zero.policy))
if (any(card(x$neighbours) == 0) && !zero.policy) 
    stop("regions with no neighbours found, use zero.policy=TRUE")
```

The status of the zero policy option when constructing a neighbour object isn't kept in the object, so I think this code is just being ultra cautious about presenting objects that have zero neighbours.  The behaviour of the `print.listw` function is documented in the help: `?print.listw`.

Comment: @ Spacedman: thank you for your answer! From here, I should be calculate Moran's I?

Comment: Probably - if all your polygons have zero neighbours you might struggle though...